# How to customize the "would you like to send you push notification" in IOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is their any way to customize the default message for receiving notification on device.
Just like i can customize locationservices message in info plist.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to do it.

A common practice though, is to show your prompt prior to asking user, therefore you get a chance to ask him using design of your app

Alternatively, you can use 3rd party solutions such as https://github.com/jlaws/JLPermissions